# Is it possible to migrate from ef core file?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, migration, database-migration

I have multiple database connection addresses that are created dynamically in my project. Is it possible to write cli commands in a file by hand and run these commands from the console?

Comment: You can always create a console app that uses your db context and calls `dbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync()`. If you really run it from CLI, you can run this console app from CLI using `dotnet run`

Comment: Are you looking for [Migration Bundles](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying#bundles)?